# ActiveMQ with C# and Apache NMS - Count messages in queue

Tags: c#, message-queue, activemq-classic, apache-nms

I'm using ActiveMQ to send and receive messages using a C# app. However I'm having some difficulty just getting a count of the messages in the queue.. Here's my code:

```
    public int GetMessageCount()
    {
        int messageCount = 0;
        Uri connecturi = new Uri(this.ActiveMQUri);

        IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(connecturi);

        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
        {
            IDestination requestDestination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, this.QueueRequestUri);

            IQueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.CreateBrowser((IQueue)requestDestination);
            IEnumerator messages = queueBrowser.GetEnumerator();

            while(messages.MoveNext())
            {
                messageCount++;
            }

            connection.Close();
            session.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }

        return messageCount;
    }
```

I thought I could use the QueueBrowser to get the count, but the IEnumerator it returns is always empty. I got the idea of using [QueueBrowser](http://timbish.blogspot.com/2010/03/just-finished-implementing-queuebrowser.html) from this page, but maybe there is another way I should be doing this?

**Update:**

The solution to the 'infinite loop' issue I found when going through the enumerator was solved by accessing the current message. It now only goes through the loop once (which is correct as there is only one message in the queue).

New while loop is:

```
while(messages.MoveNext())
{
    IMessage message = (IMessage)messages.Current;
    messageCount++;
}
```

Comment: Can you share: this code > SessionUtil.GetDestination | please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have an ActiveMq with me right now so I can not try it 
but I think the problem is you are not starting the connection. Try like this :

```
using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.start ();

     using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
     {
      //Whatever...
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this now populates the QueueBrowser's Enumerator, but although there is only 1 message in the queue, the `while(messages.MoveNext())` now runs forever in a seemly infinite loop. From nothing to too much!

Comment: I fixed the loop problem (as mentioned in update above), although I'm not quite sure what the actual issue was. However the original question was answered by starting the connection so thanks for the help!