# Why am I looping in ActiveMQ QueueBrowser?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

This snippet keeps looping through the queue browser. Apache.NMS 1.5.1, Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ 1.5.6, Broker 5.8.0

Queue size is < 200 
I checked prefetch, and it is still at default.

[ActiveMQ with C# and Apache NMS - Count messages in queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7512004) suggests checking `enumerator.Current` in the loop, but I am already doing that.

I tried setting a large prefetch with `?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=50000`, but it still loops.

```
IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(connectUri, "SNDTest");
    using (IConnection conn = connectionFactory.CreateConnection(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
    {
        conn.Start();
        using (ISession session = conn.CreateSession())
        {
            using (IQueueBrowser browser = session.CreateBrowser(errorQueue))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    var e = browser.GetEnumerator();
                    while (e.MoveNext())
                    {
                        i++;
                        IMessage m = e.Current as IMessage;
```

How do I stop the looping?

Comment: What version of the broker?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to some bugs that are fixed in the v5.9.0 snapshot builds such as, [AMQ-4487](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4487).  Try downloading a recent nightly build of the broker and running against that.